# How can I re-activate a "Like" button after the admin Page was deleted?

Tags: debugging, facebook-like

I was working on creating new Like/Send buttons for a webpage, and in the process, there was a Page made for me to access the stats (I've done this before for other webpages and it worked fine).  I eventually goofed up and wanted to delete the Page and start over.  Now I can't get the Like/Send buttons to work at all on that same webpage.  I get the following error when I parse it through the linter:
"The entity (class EntPublicUser) backed by id 122136327887239 cannot be seen by the current viewer xxxxxxxxxxx (EntID: 122136327887239)"    [x's are my user id]

I have seen a small handful of other questions related to this glitch, but haven't seen an answer.  The URL in question is http://einstein.atmos.colostate.edu/~mcnoldy/tropics/radar/
I'd really like to be able to re-establish the Like/Send buttons for that URL as soon as possible.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: An update: about a day after I posted this, the Like/Send buttons worked again... must have been some amount of time for re-scraping.  Now the only remaining issue is that there is not an Admin Page for the site where I can see who has Liked it, etc.

Comment: After giving it over a week to settle down and make sure I wasn't being too impatient, I'm still having the problem described previously.  While the Like/Send buttons do work, there is no Admin Page and Insights links after them when I'm logged in and viewing the page.  I have 4 other websites where everything works correctly, and I don't know what I would have done differently on this one.  Also, when I view my Pages on Facebook, 4 of them show up there, but not this new one.  Does anyone know how to get the Admin Page to exist and show up?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had this happen personally, but I'd guess that you can register the site on insights http://www.facebook.com/insights/ then you'd add some [open graph](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/) tags to your website templates so Facebook knows to associate the site with your insights. Here's how you say that you're the admin on your site template (replacing with your personal Facebook ID).

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="154200541" />
```

I usually make an app on Facebook for all my like buttons and other social plugins like the activity feed. Then I add the app id on my website templates so Facebook can associate the Facebook related activity on my site to the application I registered. Then I can view stats and such.

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="1234567"/>
```